# How do I use a sub from a different work book

Tags: excel, vba, error-handling

In a PERSONAL.XLSB workbook, I have this code:

```
Public Sub Password(ByVal Target As Range)
    a = ""
    For n = 1 To Len(Target)
        a = a & "*"
    Next n
    Target.NumberFormat = """" & a & """;""" & a & """;""" & a & """;""" & a & """"
End Sub
```

In my new workbook, I have this code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Address = Info.Range("AA9").Address Then
        Workbooks("PERSONAL.XLSB").Password Target
    End If
End Sub
```

I keep getting an error saying, `Compile error: Invalid use of property`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's how you run a macro from your personal workbook:

```
Application.Run "PERSONAL.XLSB!Password", Target
```

[EDIT]
It's worth noting that instead of a loop to build the * string, you could do this:

```
Public Sub Password(ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim sMask as String

    sMask = Mid(WorksheetFunction.Rept(";""" & String(Len(Target.Value), "*") & """", 4), 2)
    Target.NumberFormat = sMask

End Sub
```

Answer (score 4):

The Application.Run method shown by tigeravatar works well dynamically (i.e. everything is resolved at run time) and is the easiest way to quickly call some procedure.

If you to access lots of procedures, or use more than functions or subs, you can add a reference to the project name of Personal.xlsb (via Tools>References). You should rename the VBA project code name of Personal.xlsb from the default of "VBAProject" to something unique like "PersonalLibrary" or whatever. You then add the reference to PersonalLibrary.

You then get full access to all public functions and subs in standard modules, any sheets, and classes, early binding to classes and access to fields, properties and events.

This additionally comes with the benefits of intellisense and standard compile time checks like checking method signatures (that is to say, that arguments to a function or sub correspond to what it should be) and static typing.

(note, for Classes, you will need to use a function in a standard module of Personal.xlsb to return an instance of any class, as they are not 'creatable' by external projects)

In your case, you can access it, once adding a reference, as simply as `PersonalLibrary.Password(target)`