# Call PERSONAL macro from other workbook

Tags: vba, excel

I am working on a macro which will receive data from other file to shared template. After the user runs the macro within the shared workbook, it will update another workbook. I just want to make this as easily accessible as possible.

I don't want the users to open this template and update it manually. That's not the point. All works fine. When I call the macro from `Developer -> Macros -> Run`, the data copied to template is correct, and the update works too.

But when I set shortcut in  `Developer -> Macros -> Options` and I call the macro with shortcut from all others workbooks which are not PERSONAL, the macro stops in the middle after opening shared workbook. And it doesn't update it with data from other workbooks.

Am I missing something here guys? Any ideas?

EDIT:

My CODE:

```
    Public Sub KPI()

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    KPI = "C:\KPI Template.xlsx"

    Workbooks.Open (KPI)

    '****** <--- macro stops here - no error

    pathT = "C:\"
    fileNN = "KPI"
    filePath = Dir(pathT)

    While True

        If InStr(1, filePath, fileNN) > 0 Then

            GoTo resume1
        End If

        filePath = Dir

    Wend
    resume1:

    Workbooks.Open (pathT & filePath), ReadOnly:=True

    KPI_FileName = Dir(KPI)

    r = 8
    k = 2
    LDay = Day(Date)

    Sh_Name = Workbooks(KPI_FileName).Sheets("Check").Cells(r, 2)

    Do While Workbooks(KPI_FileName).Sheets("Check").Cells(r, 2) <> ""

        Do While Workbooks(filePath).Sheets(Sh_Name).Cells(LDay + 7, k) <> ""

            Workbooks(KPI_FileName).Sheets("Check").Cells(r, k + 1) = Workbooks(filePath).Sheets(Sh_Name).Cells(LDay + 7, k)

        k = k + 1
        Loop

    r = r + 2
    k = 2
    Sh_Name = Workbooks(KPI_FileName).Sheets("Check").Cells(r, 2)
    Loop
```

End Sub

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I use a sub from a different work book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18495046/how-do-i-use-a-sub-from-a-different-work-book)

Comment: The *title* of your question is a duplicate, but the *body* of your question is unclear. If it isn't a duplicate, please clarify.

Comment: I used to your comment link and I have set macro in `PERSONAL` as `Public Sub` but still when I call macro from another workbook by pressing shortcut ex. `Ctrl+Shift+K` macro stops in the middle of the code just after opening 1 of 2 required files. What I want to accomplish is to run `PERSONAL` macro from any workbook just by pressing shortcut.

Comment: What I mean is that when I run macro manually from `Developer -> Macros -> Run` all code works fine. No errors, but every time when I press shortcut within any other workbook. Code stops before doing all the work. I want to know why, maybe I am missing simple thing.

Comment: You need to clarify. Give enough information so that others can reproduce the problem. Please read [mcve]. In effect, you are asking for help in debugging invisible code.

Comment: The problem is likely to be one in which things like `Range()` or `Worksheet()` refer to something different depending on what the active workbook is. The solution is to adequately qualify all such references. Since you haven't shown the relevant code, I am just guessing. By the way -- when you say that it "stops in the middle of the code..." does it stop with an error message? If so, what is the message?

Comment: I have just added whole code which is in `PERSONAL` workbook. Works only when running it manually or by hitting `F5`. Stops (with no error) when hitting shortcut while in another workbook.

Comment: How do you distinguish between "the macro stops" and "the macro doesn't do what I expect it to do"? If there is no error, what leads you to identify a particular line that the macro stops at?

Comment: When I set breakpoint at `pathT = "C:\"` and run it with shortcut it open only ` Workbooks.Open (KPI)`, but when I set breakpoint at `KPI = "C:\KPI Template.xlsx"` and proceed with `F8` I can go through all steps in code. I don't know how I could simpler explain this.

Comment: I made a bit research on my case and found this. This is the closest to my problem. [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41006901/vba-code-execution-stop-when-macro-is-started-from-custom-tab-or-activex-butto). The problem was not resolved.

Comment: Problem resolved. I wasn't searching good enough. Sorry for that. [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6959005/excel-doesnt-complete-macro-after-opening-another-workbook) for reference.